# Android - get SSL certificate details (company name, EV, ...) for an SSL connection

Tags: android, security, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

my app connects to a remote HTTPS server using an SSL connection.

I need to get the certificate details.
Specifically I need the following information:

- The company name that certificate has been issued to
- If the certificate as been issued using extended validation (SSL EV)

Is it possible to get this information in Android?

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to get the details of your certificate?